# use form_for to submit data thats not selected by the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I'm following this intro to rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-new-posts

and I want to be able to add data to my form thats not chosen in a field, that is just passed as a constant.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`<%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => value %>`*

See [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)